# VB.Net Close window by title

Tags: vb.net, api, window

I'm searching a method to close a specific window by the title.

I tried with `Process.GetProcessesByName`; but not is working by this case particulary.

I'm searching a method with APIs or similar (Not in C#, I see several code but not work fine in vb.net)

Thanks!

---

UPDATE

Thanks for the reply. But I'm still have a problem with the solution that you describe me below.
I'm have an only process that's control two windows. Then, if I close (or kill) the Window #2, instantly close the first one (See the image).

By this reason I think in using an API method from the begging.

I'm only want close the second window.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using something like this. using [`Process.MainWindowTitle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowtitle) to get the Title Text and [`Process.CloseMainWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow) to close down the UI, its a little more graceful than killing the Process.

Note: Contains does a case-sensitive search

```
Imports System.Diagnostics
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim myProcesses() As Process = Process.GetProcesses

        For Each p As Process In myProcesses
            If p.MainWindowTitle.Contains("Notepad") Then
                p.CloseMainWindow()
            End If
        Next

    End Sub

End Module
```

---

As far as Win API functions try something like this. Be aware if you close the parent window you **will** close the children also.

```
Module Module1
    Private Declare Auto Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" (ByVal parentHandle As Integer, _
                                               ByVal childAfter As Integer, _
                                               ByVal lclassName As String, _
                                               ByVal windowTitle As String) As Integer

    Private Declare Auto Function PostMessage Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Integer, _
                                                            ByVal message As UInteger, _
                                                            ByVal wParam As Integer, _
                                                            ByVal lParam As Integer) As Boolean

    Dim WM_QUIT As UInteger = &H12
    Dim WM_CLOSE As UInteger = &H10


    Sub Main()
        Dim handle As Integer = FindWindowEx(0, 0, Nothing, "YourFormsTitle")
        PostMessage(handle, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0)
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Thanks by your reply Mark, but in still have problems with your solution. See my comments in the first post

Comment: @MiBol So I gather by what you are saying is, Your process has multiple windows and you want to Close down one of them but not the other?

Comment: Exactly, but if I close the window #2 (In the image), automatically close the window #1. If I do it manually this doesn't happen.

Comment: @MiBol which Window is the Parent Window?

Comment: The window with the title "SAP Logon 710"

Comment: @MiBol even using the Windows Api, if you send a close message it will close out both forms if you close the parent. I will post the API functions so you can experiment with it

Comment: Mark, thanks a lot by all your input. Indeed, the process that you shared with me closes the both windows of the root process.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't showed us your code snippet. Perhaps you can try this one.

```
Dim processList() As Process
processList = Process.GetProcessesByName(ListBox1.Items(ListBox1.SelectedIndex).ToString)

For Each proc As Process In processList
    If MsgBox("Terminate " & proc.ProcessName & "?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Terminate?") = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
        Try
            proc.Kill()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End If
Next
```

In the snippet above, i have a list of window title on the `listBox`. The snippet will iterate the listbox for window titles, and if the title has been found, it asks a message to terminate the process or not.

Comment: Thanks a lot by your solution. But, I'm still have problems, please refer to the first post for more information.